# WebView size in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

when I run my material design site in Chrome, it is displayed like:

[image]

But when I run in `WebView`, it is displayed like

[image]

I want to display it in `WebView` like it does in Chrome

Code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.zoom = "+String.valueOf(scale)+";");
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://site");
    }
```

Comment: make sure the fonts that you are using are available in your app

Comment: also share the code for that piece of your view

Comment: how i can fixing the problem please write ready code @AndroidMechanic

Comment: No one here is going to write the code for you. :) Share what you have tried and we can help you understand what is going wrong,

Comment: My question is very clear .. When using the site in Google Chrome appears new and nice, but when I use the site at WeView shows badly

Comment: Maybe you can start share your web code, so we can review it

Comment: I did not understand you @HendraWijayaDjiono :/

Comment: @JackKing If you own the web in myWebView.loadUrl("http://site");, than you can share your code. The problem might not be the java problem, but the web code problem